# How can I display and hide a div with [ngStyle] after doing click on a <button>

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-style

I´m trying to display a div after doing a click on a button. this click calls a function from my component.ts.

I want to display the results on this , but I want that this remains hidden, before I call this function, I dont really get the solution,thats could be maybe easier with Jquery..but I dont use it with Angular yet.

I´d thank any help..thanks a lot  :))

the code, first the view

```html
<div id="titulo-filme">
  <h2>{{ titulo }}</h2>
 </div>
 <div id="film-jahren">
  <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let dato of datos;let indice = index">
     {{ dato.year }}
   <button #btnInfo type="button" [disabled]="click[indice]" (click)="**verInfoPorIndice(indice)**; click[indice] = true "><img src="../assets/images/claqueta.png"></button>
   </li> 
  </ul>  
 </div>
 

 <div id="filmContent" #filmContent [ngStyle]="{'display':infoFilm ? 'block' : 'none'}">  
  <ul *ngFor="let film of infoFilm; let indice = index">
   <li [ngStyle]="{'color':film.year == 1920 ? 'red' : 'white' }">{{ film.year }}</li>
   <li>Titel: {{ film.name }}</li>
   <li>Genre: {{ film.gender }}</li>
   <li> Hauptrolle: {{ film.mainrole }}</li>
   <li>Regisseur: {{ film.director }}</li>
   <li [ngStyle]="{'align-content':film.year > 1895 ? 'center' : 'center'}"><p><img src="../assets/images/{{ film.bild }}"></p></li>    
  </ul>
  <br>  
 </div>
```

and the function in filme.component.ts

```html
verInfoPorIndice(indice){

   if(this.films.indexOf(indice)){    
     
    this.infoFilm.push(this.films[indice]);
   
    return this.infoFilm;
   }

  }
```

Comment: You should use `*ngIf="infoFilm "`  https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: I did like you suggested, but I doesn´t work...<div id="filmContent" #filmContent *ngIf="infoFilm" [style.display]="infoFilm ? 'block' : 'none'">  :(((

Comment: I did like you suggested, but I doesn´t work...<div id="filmContent" #filmContent *ngIf="infoFilm" [style.display]="infoFilm ? 'block' : 'none'">  :(((

Comment: You should remove the styling in total what ngIf will do is show it or not show it. Based on a true or false statement or defined or undefined

Comment: Hi , thanks ,you habe been very helpfull, it works!!, but the css styles are lost!! how I suposedely configure the styles of my div?

Comment: <div #filmContent *ngIf="infoFilm" [style.display]="infoFilm ? 'block':'none'">  
  <ul *ngFor="let film of infoFilm; let indice = index">
   <li>{{ film.year }}</li>
   <li>Titel: {{ film.name }}</li>
   <li>Genre: {{ film.gender }}</li>
   <li> Hauptrolle: {{ film.mainrole }}</li>
   <li>Regisseur: {{ film.director }}</li>
   <li><p><img src="../assets/images/{{ film.bild }}"></p></li>    
  </ul>
  <br>  
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Just use `*ngIf` and check whether the length of array contains elements `*ngIf="infoFilm && infoFilm.length > 0"`:

```
<div id="titulo-filme">
    <h2>{{ titulo }}</h2>
</div>
<div id="film-jahren">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let dato of datos;let indice = index">
                {{ dato.year }}
            <button #btnInfo type="button" [disabled]="click[indice]" 
                (click)="verInfoPorIndice(indice); click[indice] = true ">
            <img src="../assets/images/claqueta.png"></button>
        </li>   
    </ul>   
</div>


<div id="filmContent" #filmContent *ngIf="infoFilm && infoFilm.length > 0">     
    <ul *ngFor="let film of infoFilm; let indice = index">
        <li [ngStyle]="{'color':film.year == 1920 ? 'red' : 'white' }">{{ film.year }}</li>
        <li>Titel: {{ film.name }}</li>
        <li>Genre: {{ film.gender }}</li>
        <li> Hauptrolle: {{ film.mainrole }}</li>
        <li>Regisseur: {{ film.director }}</li>
        <li [ngStyle]="{'align-content':film.year > 1895 ? 'center' : 'center'}"><p> 
        <img src="../assets/images/{{ film.bild }}"></p></li>               
    </ul>
    <br>        
</div>
```

Comment: @serenimus I am great that it helped to you!:) [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)